# Web browser hangs upon Drag And Drop Keyword for robot framework

Tags: drag-and-drop, robotframework

I am currently using Robot Framework to automate my test cases. In one of the test cases I have, I need to drag and drop a certain element. Upon using the SeleniumLibrary keyword Drag And Drop, my browser just hangs. Has anyone encountered this same error? Is there a work around I can use?

I am using Robot Framework 2.7 and running my tests on IE8 and FF9.

Here is sample code:
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  10s  5s  Element Should Be Visible

```
//td[@class='policy_td']//ul[@class='workgroup_list']
```

---

```
Drag And Drop  //ul[@id='unused_workgroup_ul']//li[@class='workgroup']//span//span[text()='Test']  target=//td[@class='policy_td']//ul[@class='workgroup_list']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. You should define element by locator using xpath, and later use it as the target. For example, part of your code could look like:

```
Assign Id To Element xpath=//td[@class='policy_td']//ul[@class='workgroup_list'] ID

Drag And Drop //ul[@id='unused_workgroup_ul']//li[@class='workgroup']//span//span[text()='Test'] target=ID
```